# Python while loop is not waiting for user input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still learning python so bear in mind as I'm not an expert, I'm trying to create a small program that will create a file base on the user input,

the first menu will contain some barcode of device, each time the barcode scanner scan, the device is sending automatically an enter, hence why I've made a `while True:` in order to allow multiple inputs, once the scan is finished then the user will go to the next menu by pressing CTRL+D

The code below work until it calls the next menu but stops (it should ask the user to input the next value )

```
def netmap_mac():
    clear()
    header_function()
    print('Start by scanning the mac address of the device: ')
    print('When finish press <CTRL+D>')
    mac = []
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            return netmap_ip()
        mac.append(line)
    print(mac)

def netmap_ip():
    clear()
    header_function()
    print('Enter the mangement IP for each MAC you scanned: ')
    print('When finish press <CTRL+D>')
    ip = input()
    print ('This is netmap_ip()')
```

I understand my issue, the while loop remain `True`, but I'm not sure how to close it

I believe while loop would be my only easy option as the barcode scanner is sending Enter automatically once the scan is finished for each barcode

I'm running python3

Comment: Please describe the required flow of your program. when do you want input in while. when single one. what netmap_ip() should return?

Comment: my program is mainly a bunch of user input and menu to guide the user, it will at the end save the user input into a file,

netmap_ip() is the next user input of my program, user should provide the IP for each barcode scanned during netmap_mac()

Comment: after the first Ctrl-D do you expect to add another one user input of ip and then exit? or several?

Comment: so the ip need to match the amount of MAC that has been scanned, ie: if the user has scan 10 mac address, 10 IP would need to be entered, I dont have enough experience to make a validation mechanism, so I would trust the user input for now. to answer you question, I'm expecting several

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your described flow, here is the code.
1. you should break the while
2. you should add a while to the netmap_ip function

```
def netmap_mac():
    # clear()
    # header_function()
    print('Start by scanning the mac address of the device: ')
    print('When finish press <CTRL+D>')
    mac = []
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
            mac.append(line)
        except EOFError:
            break

    print(mac)
    netmap_ip()

def netmap_ip():
    # clear()
    # header_function()
    print('Enter the mangement IP for each MAC you scanned: ')
    print('When finish press <CTRL+D>')
    ips = []
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
            ips.append(line)
        except EOFError:
            break

    print ('This is netmap_ip()')
    print(ips)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  netmap_mac()
```

Update:

output:

```
Start by scanning the mac address of the device:
When finish press <CTRL+D>
mac1
mac2  # -> press Ctrl-D
['mac1', 'mac2']
Enter the mangement IP for each MAC you scanned:
When finish press <CTRL+D>
ip1
ip2  # -> press Ctrl-D
This is netmap_ip()
['ip1', 'ip2']
```

Comment: thanks Lior, I've tested the code - it doesn't allow me to input anything on netmap_ip() it actually stop the code: Process finished with exit code 0, I have the same issue previously

Comment: weird. I added the console output of the program. It seems to be working. Is this what you expect?

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for, not sure why mine wouldn't give the same, here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/gWkVmVnR - I'm using python 3.7

Comment: it is working. check: https://repl.it/@liorcohen/ColossalAccurateMention

Comment: correct I'm on windows to develop the script, but it will be executed on a linux server once finish

Comment: I am afraid Ctrl-D is a linux thing.

Comment: use if line: ..... else: break instead of the EOFError. double enter will reach the break (instead ctrl-D)